# Restrict a link tag with fadeIN function to have the smoothscroll effect

Tags: jquery, fadein, smooth-scrolling

i have a one page website with smooth scrolling effect when an `a` tag (navigation) is clicked, one of those navigation entry also calls a hidden div(input.box) with fadeIN function, my problem is whenever that entry with fadeIN function shows, the page also slides down a little bit. How should i restrict this menu with fadein function from scrolling also? I have the codes i used for smoothscroll and fadein on my jsfiddle bellow.

[Smooth Scroll Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9tE/)

[FadeIN Effect Code](http://jsfiddle.net/ET544/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following part of your smooth scroll code selects the elements for which to apply the effect:

```
$('a[href*=#]')
```

You need to restrict that to exclude the anchor that opens the popup. The approach to doing this depends on how you identify the element to exclude:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not(a[href="#info"])')
```

or

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not(.info-popup)')
```

One could also argue that it would be neater if the criteria was the other way around, so that the elements that should be targeted for smooth scrolling needs to be actively selected, rather than filtered out:

```
$('a.page-nav')
```

Comment: Thanks for looking out. I tried already your last example before posting but sadly it didn't workedout.. already tried your first and second both didn't either. Could i missed something on smooth scroll code? Thanks again.

Comment: The fading div actually doesn't scroll smoothly it just jump a little bit down.

Comment: @jmc: Oh, by your last comment, it looks like the smooth scroll effect is in fact not applied to that element. I think what happens then is that the anchor navigates to your hash, which explains the jumpy appearance. What you need to do is simply to `return false;` in the anchor's click listener, after opening the popup, so that the browser won't follow the anchor to its `href`.